# How do I put an address for private class members into EAX?

Tags: c++, class, assembly, this

Can you help me get the address of a private class member into EAX?  Like `mov eax, this->??`.

```
class Example
{
    private :
        int a;
        int b;

    public :
    void SetValues(int p1, const int &p2)
    {
        asm
        {
          mov eax, this-> /* How do I get the address of private members? */
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Which compiler/inline assembler? VC++ can reference any C++ symbol if it's in scope, IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

What compiler? It seems to be convention that the value for 'this' is held in the ecx register. The address of any member, it makes no difference if they're public or private, will be an offset from 'this', which depends on the order of their declaration in the class declaration.

In your example, the address of 'a' would be 'ecx' and the address of 'b' would be 'ecx + sizeof(int)', assuming there's no vtable.

You could also use the 'lea' instruction.

Comment: And then things get really ugly if there are any base classes or if you have virtual functions. There could also be alignment padding.

Comment: Sorry for my English. Yes, i tryed via edx. And lea, and mov. I can read values via edx. But to set - i can not. IDE - C++ Builder.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why'd you ever want to do this, but here is a functioning example with gcc

```
void SetValues(int p1, const int &p2) // what are these arguments for?
{
    __asm__(
        "movl %0, %%eax"    // movl src, dest. you may need to reverse operands
        : // no outputs
        : "r"(&this->a) // %0 will hold the address of a
    );
}
```

if you're on 64 bit, the <s>right</s> slightly less awful way to do this would be with `movq` and `rax`

```
void SetValues(int p1, const int &p2)
{
    __asm__(
        "movq %0, %%rax"
        : // no outputs
        : "r"(&this->a)
    );
}
```

Comment: The solution is very interesting. But it does not change the fact. In any case, you should try to get direct access.

Comment: @Columbo assuming 64 bit, yes.  I implemented it with rax myself, but the request for eax made me think OP is on 32 bit system

Comment: If you are using gcc, how about just `__asm__("# do something with eax" : : "a"(&this->a) );`?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all! Question withdrawn. In fact, everything is very simple.

set p1 to Example::a.

```
lea eax, this
mov edx,  p1
mov [eax], edx
```

Address of second member [this + 4]
But second param as const int &.
It for tomorrow.